# Ho to convert a pd data frame to matrix structure in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have my data for a user's dialing pattern as below:

```
user   No.     call_Frequency      Hour_of_call
P1    1212     3                     2
P1    1212     5                     3
P1    1111     3                     4
P1    3456     2                     5
```

Hour of the call is at what time no. has been called and `call_Frequency` is how many times the no. is dialed for that hour.

I have generated my output as following:

```
       Hour
No.  **2    3    4       5**
1212   3    5    0       0
1111   0    0    3       0
3456   0    0    0       13
```

But I want to get output for 24 hours of the day. The output that I am looking for should have all 24 hours as headers and corresponding should have values 0 for hour where there is no call:

```
       Hour
No.    1    2    3    4     5.......    24
1212   0    3    5    0     0.....      0
1111   0    0    0    3     0.....      0
3456   0    0    0    0     13.....     0
```

Comment: @akrun can you help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with this data frame:

```
   Hour_of_call   No.  call_Frequency user
0             2  1212               3   P1
1             3  1212               5   P1
2             4  1111               3   P1
3             5  3456               2   P1
```

Group by number:

```
grouped = df.groupby('No.')
```

Write a function that puts a zero for missing calls:

```
def func(t):
    hours = set(t['Hour_of_call'].values)
    calls = iter(t['call_Frequency'].values)  
    return pd.Series([0 if x not in hours else next(calls)
            for x in range(1, 25)])
```

Apply this function:

```
res = grouped.apply(func)
```

Make the hours start with `1` instead of `0`.

```
res.columns = range(1, 25)
```

The result `res` should look like this:

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 ...  23  24
No.                                                                        
1111   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0 
1212   0   3   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   
3456   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0
```